# javascript/jquery add error message

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the next input field:

```
<form action="admin" method="POST" commandName="adminForm" onsubmit="return validateEmail(this.email)">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="email">Email</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="email" name="email" type="text" path="email" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please fill this field - it is mandatory')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

```js
function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
    if (!re.test(email.value)) {
        email.setAttribute("oninvalid", "this.setCustomValidity('Wrong email format')");
        email.setAttribute("oninput", "setCustomValidity('')");
        return false;
    }
    return re.test(email.value);
}
```

Here I want to display error message when the wrong email is added. Now when I do not add something under the email field, it shows error `Please fill this field - it is mandatory`. I want to change this message if email is wrong.

It currently does not work, any ideas why?

Comment: What are you expecting your code to do?

Comment: As I wrote in my question. Now when I do not add smth under email field, it shows error "Please fill this field - it is mandatory". Now what I want - change this message if email is wrong.

Comment: Can't you change the html? If not this won't work, the error is called before your code can change the message

Comment: @Darren Sweeney - what do you mean by changing html?

Comment: Your question made no mention of that - I have updated it for you.

Comment: try this., `<input type="email" required>`

Comment: @Sathish - did not understand how it can help me? required helps when the field is empty, but it is not my current problem.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ono1heae/ works. debug from there

Answer (score 1):

Refer to my example source.

html

```
<form id="myForm" action="admin" method="POST">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="email">Email</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="email" name="email" type="text">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="msg"></div>
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

and javascript

```
var form = document.getElementById('myForm');
var msg = document.getElementById('msg');
form.addEventListener('submit', function( e ) {


    var re = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;

    if (!re.test(email)) {

        console.log('invalid');
        msg.innerText = 'invalid email';
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        msg.innerText = '';
    }
});
```

and [live demo](http://codepen.io/b6pzeusbc54tvhw5jgpyw8pwz2x6gs/pen/zrOpva?editors=101)

Comment: This is not what I asked but also suite to me)))